# Strong Name for Microsoft.Practices.Composite-DLL leads to compiler error

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I would like to sign all projects in my C# solution. But when I try to do so, there is the problem, that several third party assemblies don't have a strong name. These assemblies are:

- Microsoft.Practices.Composite.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll

After doing some research I found a way to give third party DLLs a strong name ([source](http://erjjones.github.io/blog/How-to-sign-third-party-assemblies/)):

```
1) ildasm /all /out=ThirdParty.il ThirdParty.dll
2) ilasm /dll /key=YourKey.snk ThirdParty.il
```

These operations both complete successful. But when I remove the NuGet packages with the unsigned assemblies from my projects and add the signed ones as references, I get the following compiler error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.EventBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Composite, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

But of course I already added Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll

To confine the problem, I tried to add the reference to a new project. But since I got the same error there, I can exclude some weird configuration in my main solution.

You can download my test-project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7sqb4vtbnasfjz/ConsoleApplication1.zip?dl=0

I really hope that you can help me in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I found out that the Composite Library is part of Prism since version 4. So instead of adding references to the dlls signed by me, I added the NuGet Package for Prism, which is already signed.